# Deconstructing vs dot notation in React applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've noticed that in many React.js examples, `props` are deconstructed before they are used in components. For example, the following is from [React-Redux sample code](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html):

```
class AsyncApp extends Component {
    ....
    componentDidMount() {
        const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props // <-- destructuring
        dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
    }
    ....
}
```

Isn't the code equivalent to the following? Is it just a matter of style?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(this.props.selectedSubreddit))
}
```

Comment: It is equivalent. The deconstructing notation helps more in readability in this case.

Comment: But, strictly, the code with deconstructing is equivalent to: const dispatch = this.props.dispatch; const selectedSubreddit = this.props.selectedSubreddit;

Comment: You could easily check ES5 version of your code using [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=Node-8&browsers=&builtIns=true&debug=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBA3jAJgSwgBwIZWACwDQwQCmANkcFEYgMoCuARgE5UqwC-MAvDFDqgHRpGINBBgB6cTAA8AWllIi0RrQq1GyMAHMAsACgYho4ZTosuABQAzIthwAFENAgBJKwDkiVKheJkKVHRMLMhQAJRhQA)

Comment: The code is equivalent to : const dispatch = this.props.dispatch; const selectedSubreddit = this.props.selectedSubreddit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking it is not equivalent, but both sequences yield same result in the end. And for many, example that uses destructuring is nicer to read. Theoretically, code with destructuring could be made very slightly faster, but I doubt there is any real life difference or that this is commonly taken into account when selecting between two styles.